# Discord.py program using 100% of a core

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, gpiozero

I have a Discord bot running in python on a Raspberry Pi 3B+. The purpose of this program is to send the lab status to our server by the push of a physical button. I've noticed that the program itself does not always want to cooperate and has been using 100% of a core at all times. I believe the hardware is still healthy and the only other thing that's running is the OS itself. htop reads that the individual program is using 98-101% of a core every time I check.

```
from os import system
from datetime import date
from time import sleep

from gpiozero import LED, Button
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import asyncio

# Pull in server token and channel ID
with open('/home/pi/EVC-Discord-Bot/token.txt', 'r') as f:
    TOKEN = f.read()
with open('/home/pi/EVC-Discord-Bot/channel.txt', 'r') as f:
    CHANNEL = f.read()

# Define bot properties
description = '''EVC Lab Bot'''
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description=description)

# Define client
client = discord.Client()

# Button and LED GPIO pins
openbutton=Button(17)
pendingbutton=Button(27)
closedbutton=Button(22)
###
openlight=LED(4)
pendinglight=LED(23)
closedlight=LED(24)

# Saved Messages
openmessage=':green_circle: :radio_button: :radio_button: OPEN :green_circle: :radio_button: :radio_button:'
pendingmessage=':radio_button: :yellow_circle: :radio_button: PENDING :radio_button: :yellow_circle: :radio_button:'
closedmessage=':radio_button: :radio_button: :red_circle: CLOSED :radio_button: :radio_button: :red_circle:'

print('Program Initialized')

@bot.event
async def msg(status):
    # Define desired channel
    channel = bot.get_channel(int(CHANNEL))
    # Terminal print channel and status
    print('Bot channel: ' + str(channel))
    print('Channel int: ' + str(CHANNEL))
    print('Sending message...')
    # Print respective status
    if status == 'open':
        await channel.send(openmessage)
    elif status == 'pending':
        await channel.send(pendingmessage)
    elif status == 'closed':
        await channel.send(closedmessage)
    # Terminal print "completed"
    print('Finished.')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # Tell me on_ready() def has started
    print('On ready!')
    # Endless while loop
    while True:
        # Open status
        if openbutton.is_pressed:
            # Show status in terminal
            print('Green Button Pressed')
            # Call server message function
            await msg('open')
            # Toggle open light
            openlight.on()
            # Toggle pending light
            pendinglight.off()
            # Toggle closed light
            closedlight.off()
            # Wait for active button to be released
            openbutton.wait_for_release()
            # Sleep for spam-safety
            sleep(10)
        # Pending status
        elif pendingbutton.is_pressed:
            # Show status in terminal
            print('Yellow Button Pressed')
            # Call server message function
            await msg('pending')
            # Toggle open light
            openlight.off()
            # Toggle pending light
            pendinglight.on()
            # Toggle closed light
            closedlight.off()
            # Wait for active button to be released
            pendingbutton.wait_for_release()
            # Sleep for spam-safety
            sleep(10)
        # Closed status
        elif closedbutton.is_pressed:
            # Show status in terminal
            print('Red Button Pressed')
            # Call server message function
            await msg('closed')
            # Toggle open light
            openlight.off()
            # Toggle pending light
            pendinglight.off()
            # Toggle closed light
            closedlight.on()
            # Wait for active button to be released
            closedbutton.wait_for_release()
            # Sleep for spam-safety
            sleep(10)

# Start bot
bot.run(TOKEN)
# Tell me the bot booted
print('Bot is booted')
```

Answer (score 4):

If no button is pressed, your `on_ready` is basically

```py
async def on_ready():
    print('On ready!')
    while True:
        pass
```

which of course hogs 100% CPU!

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I'll be considering this on my next revision. Do you know of a way to keep it from looping so CPU hungry like that?